# Add new SQL table from this query

Tags: sql

I've this query:

```
SELECT KDX_PostalAddress_Country,
       COUNT(KDX_Id) * 100 /
  (SELECT COUNT(KDX_Id)
   FROM ___Kardex) AS KDX_CountryPercentage,
       COUNT(KDX_Id) AS KDX_CountryCount
FROM ___Kardex
WHERE KDX_HotelId=:hotel_id
GROUP BY KDX_PostalAddress_Country
ORDER BY KDX_CountryPercentage DESC
```

Actually the KDX_PostalAddress_Country returns country codes like CA, FR, IT.

How can I add my new table which contains all city code like this:

Table is `___CountryList`:
`CTY_Code` (CA, FR, IT)
`CTY_en` (Canada, France, Italy)

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/2523/insert-into-new-sql-table-with-select-into/

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? In standard SQL this would be `create table __CountryList as select ...`.